# Custom Routes not working - 404 not found

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm trying to create a custom route.  The must be in this format: `http://localhost:8000/home-back-to-school` but instead I get a 404 not found error.  `http://localhost:8000/posts/home-back-to-school` works, but that's not what I'm trying to get working.

My routes on web.php are defined as: `Route::resource('posts',PostsController::class);` 
I modified the Route Service Provider by adding the code below:

```
 parent::boot();

    Route::bind('post',function($slug){

        return Post::published()->where('slug',$slug)->first();
    });
```

The published scope is defined in the Post Model file(Post.php) as:

```
  public function scopePublished()
{
    return $this->where('published_at','<=',today())->orderBy('published_at', 'desc');
}
```

I've done previously with laravel 5.x, now struggling with laravel 8.x
Link to the Documentation: [Laravel 8 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes)

Comment: So define a route that matches the `home-back-to-school` pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a custom route since you don't want to use the resourceful route for this method.

**In your web.php**

```
// Keep all your resource routes except the 'show' route since you want to customize it
Route::resource('posts', PostsController::class)->except(['show']);

// Define a custom route for the show controller method
Route::get('{slug}', PostsController::class)->name('posts.show');
```

**In your PostController:**

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
```

**In your Post model:**

```
// Tell Laravel your model key isn't the default ID anymore since you want to use the slug 
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

---

You may have to fix your other Post routes to make them work with this change since you are now using `$post->slug`  instead of `$post->id` as the model key.

Read more about customizing the model key:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name

You should also remove the code you have in the boot method and use the controller instead.

Finally, make sure your post slug is always unique for obvious reason.

---

**Note:**

You may run into problems if your other routes are not related to the `Post` model.

Imagine if you have a route called `example.com/contact-us`. Laravel has no way to "guess" if this route should be sent to the PostController or the ContactController. `contact-us` could be a Post slug or it could be a static route to your contact page. That's why it's generally a good idea to start your urls with the model name. In your case, it would be a good idea for your Post route to start with "/posts/" like this: `http://example.com/posts/your-post-slug`. Otherwise you may run into all sorts unexpected routing issues.

**Don't fight the framework: Always follow best practices and naming conventions when you can.**